# Can python-keyring dump all passwords?

Tags: python, python-keyring

Using [python-keyring](https://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib), can one dump all of the available passwords?  I'm looking for an `iterate_passwords()` or similar, but it doesn't seem to exist.

According to [this blog post](http://blog.schmichael.com/2008/10/30/listing-all-passwords-stored-in-gnome-keyring/), this is possible using `gnomekeyring`, but I can't find anything similar in python-keyring, which appears to be a much more prevalent library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `python-keyring` documentation, the [keyring backends](https://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib#rst-header-write-your-own-keyring-backend) only specify `get_`, `set_` and `delete_` methods for single passwords. For example, see the [Gnome backend](https://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib/src/8aadf61db38c70a5fe76fbe013df25fa62c03a8d/keyring/backends/Gnome.py?at=default).

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/issues/151) on this, which states:

> The current API does not provide a way to enumerate keys.